# Maven: is it possible to use a conditional properties filtering?

Tags: maven

As we know there is a very useful option in Maven Resource plugin: we can use filtering to replace the placeholders in some resources files with some predefined values. The explanation can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

A question is: is it possible to use a conditional filtering? I.e. I want to replace some placeholders in my files but I want to do it basing on some conditions, for example:

> if the value of myProperty = "DevelopmentSetup" then the replacement
>   comes from development.properties, otherwise use "ProductionSetup".

Can I do it with Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot configure Maven's resource plugin to use conditional filtering (at least as far as I know), it is still possible with Maven to select a build profile based on the value of a particular property. As described on [Maven - Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), you can activate a particular profile when some property has a given value (scroll down to 'The profile below will activate the profile when the system property "debug" is specified with any value').

So, the solution to your problem would be to set up two profiles, `development` and `production`. In these profiles, you configure your resource filter settings accordingly to either use your development property file or production property file.

There is also some useful information in [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html). Especially the tips and tricks section.

Comment: Roland, great idea with profiles, but in my case I have to activate several ones.. The point is that I have some setting file and I want to populate the properties in that file basing on their first value. For example:
database.name=MY_DATABASE
database.url=${database.url}

database.name=OUR_DATABASE
database.url=${database.url}

Comment: I mean basing on database.name value I want to put into database.url this value or that from some property file.